# Unable to run cucumber in grails

Tags: grails, cucumber

I am trying to run cucumber in grails. I get the following error.

```
Error |
Error loading event script from file [C:\Users\target\work\plugins\cucumber-0.9.0\scripts\_Events.groovy] No such property: ant
for class: _GrailsSettings (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
.....................................................................
|Server stopped
Error |
Fatal error running tests: taskdef class org.codehaus.groovy.grails.compiler.Gra
ilsc cannot be found
 using the classloader AntClassLoader[] (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)

.Tests FAILED
|
 - view reports in C:\Users\target\test-reports
Error |
Error running forked test-app: taskdef class org.codehaus.groovy.grails.compiler
.Grailsc cannot be found
 using the classloader AntClassLoader[] (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)

| Error Forked Grails VM exited with error
```

What might cause this, and how do I solve it?

Comment: Can you run the app with the verbose mode. Since the above logs are not quite detailed.
In grails command : run-app --verbose and provide us the detailed log here. Regards,

Comment: Actually i am running this using command "grails test-app" in grails 2.3.4

Answer (score 4):

Finally I found it its because i am using grails 2.3.x in this we have forked execution, which cucumber plugin do not work so delete grails.project.fork=[  ] form buidconfig.groovy Then this should work